# Posting data to external websites, not just your own

Tags: php

On PHP you have file_get_content to get the content of a page, not just your own pages, but ANYONE's page. So I'm wondering if there's a way to POST to ANYONE's website as well. So, for example. If I made an account on a forum, and want to sign in and get the content of the page, I would be able to do that remotely, by using PHP as opposing to typing in my username and password to see the website. I realize that this question may be down voted, but I just want to know if this is possible.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php

Comment: Yes, you can post to anyone's website. That's why you see Captcha images on the web, to prevent 'robots' to post to your website. Search google for "posting data to external domain using PHP"

Comment: @ThiagoPXP Yeah. All the answers I've found are convoluted and expresses little to no explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Posting data to external websites, not just your own"
>
> I just want to know if this is possible.

**Yes**, it's possible.

You can use the [curl library](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for that.

Here's a small example:

```
$url = 'http://remotedomain.com/post.php';
$fields = array(
                'username' => "myusername",
                'password' => "mypassword"
                );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
//server response in now on $result

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```